# assign zero before decimal value in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table `tst_fr` where i have column Dur which is `varchar` datatype. In this table there are lot of values which is starting with decimal for example `.16`.

I need to assign `0` before that decimal value for example `0.16`.

I tried with below query but it didnt worked and just returning as `0` for all the decimal starting values:

```
Select to_char(round(to_number(DUR) / (1024*1024), 3),0999) as DUR
from tst_fr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
Select to_char(
         round(to_number(DUR)/(1024*1024), 3),
         'fm9990.999'
       ) as DUR
from   tst_fr
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tst_fr (dur) AS
SELECT 0.16 * 1024*1024 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234.5678 * 1024*1024 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DUR |
> | --- |
> | 0.16 |
> | 1234.568 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=35bbd299b91978773f743e5d47ab664f)*

Comment: @MTO its not working somehow and also the other values which are not starting with Decimal got affected...i think we need to apply case when condition and check only those values which are starting as decimal for example .16 and remaining it should be same...currently for all decimal point starting value it returns as 0.

Comment: @Andrew Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71411230/edit) your question to include a [MRE] with the sample data that replicates the problem (as DDL/DML statements we can copy/paste) and the expected output for that sample data. Just saying "its not working somehow" is not a constructive statement as it doesn't tell us what isn't working and how it isn't working.

Comment: @MTO its working now i used the same query previously it was with data type issue